# I'm Facing an error while testing with react-testing Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reducerPath') with react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm Trying to test component PostCard.js that do serten things

Note: I didn't provide the styled-components in this snippet

```
/* eslint-disable */
// Libraries
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { PropTypes } from "prop-types";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  useGetSearchedUserDetailsMutation,
  useLikeMutation,
} from "../../redux/services/user/userApi";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  selectUser,
  setSearchedUserDetails,
} from "../../redux/services/user/userSlice";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
// import { IconsBlobUrl } from "./../../services/BlobServices";

// Assets

const Like = `./icons/cards/like.png`;
const PostCard = ({
  img,
  postId,
  userId,
  cover,
  className,
  onClickHandler,
  name,
  isProfile,
  onClickLike,
}) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const { user } = useSelector(selectUser);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [getSearchedUser] = useGetSearchedUserDetailsMutation();
  const [sendLikeData, { isSuccess: isLikeSucess }] = useLikeMutation();
  const handleClick = () => {
    getSearchedUser({
      profileId: userId,
    }).then((res) => {
      if (userId !== user?.pk) {
        dispatch(setSearchedUserDetails(res.data["Profile Details"]));
        navigate("/users");
      } else {
        navigate("/profile");
      }
    });
  };
  const handleLikeClick = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    sendLikeData({
      post_id: postId,
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLikeSucess) {
      toast.success("Liked");
    }
  }, [isLikeSucess]);

  return (
    <StyledCardContainer>
      {!isProfile && (
        <CardHeader>
          <CardLogoContainer onClick={() => handleClick()}>
            <CardLogo src={img} />
          </CardLogoContainer>
          <CardInfoContainer>
            <Text>{name}</Text>
          </CardInfoContainer>
        </CardHeader>
      )}
      <StyledCard
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${cover})`,
          direction: "ltr",
        }}
        className={className}
        whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }}
        onClick={onClickHandler}
      >
        <LablesContainer>
          <LikesLabel></LikesLabel>
          <LikeBtn
            onClick={(e) => handleLikeClick(e)}
            data-testid="like-button"
          />
        </LablesContainer>
      </StyledCard>
    </StyledCardContainer>
  );
};

const CardHeader = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 50%;
`;
```

And this is a simple test file to test that didn't run at all
I tried many solution provided by ChatGPT and other solutions but nothing work

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import PostCard from "../PostCard"; // Import the correct component
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import store from "../../../redux/store";
const persistor = persistStore(store);

describe("PostCard Component", () => {
    const img = "/path/to/image.jpg";
    const postId = 1;
    const userId = 123;
    const cover = "/path/to/cover.jpg";
    const className = "custom-class";
    const onClickHandler = jest.fn();
    const onClickLike = jest.fn();
    const name = "John Doe";

    it("should render with provided props", async () => {
        render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
                    <PostCard
                        img={img}
                        postId={postId}
                        userId={userId}
                        cover={cover}
                        className={className}
                        onClickHandler={onClickHandler}
                        onClickLike={onClickLike}
                        name={name}
                    />
                </PersistGate>
            </Provider>
        );

        const imageElement = await screen.findByAltText("Post Cover Image");
        const nameElement = await screen.findByText(name);

        expect(imageElement).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(nameElement).toHaveTextContent(name);
    });

    it("Should be triggered when onClick is called by button", async () => {
        render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
                    <PostCard
                        img={img}
                        postId={postId}
                        userId={userId}
                        cover={cover}
                        className={className}
                        onClickHandler={onClickHandler}
                        onClickLike={onClickLike}
                        name={name}
                    />
                </PersistGate>
            </Provider>
        );

        const likeButton = await screen.findByTestId("like-button");
        fireEvent.click(likeButton);
        expect(onClickLike).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

**The Error of the Console when I run npm test**
*Test suite failed to run
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reducerPath')
> 42 |   [userApi.reducerPath]: userApi.reducer,
|            ^*

Snippet of store.js

```
import { userApi } from "./services/user/userApi";
const reducers = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  [userApi.reducerPath]: userApi.reducer,
});
```

Snippet of userApiSlice.js

```
import { createApi } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import baseQueryWithReauth from "../../baseQuery";
export const userApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "userApi",
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    signin: builder.mutation({
      query: (body) => {
        return {
          url: "/social/api/login",
          method: "post",
          body,
        };
      },
    }),
  }),
});
export const { useSigninMutation } = userApi;
```

Comment: Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] that includes all relevant code you are working with and have an issue using? This seems to be an issue with the `userApi` API slice.

Comment: I think this *might* sometimes happen if you have some code that is trying to import and use the store prior the store importing `userApi`, something like a circular dependency. Think you could try creating a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Why are you persisting data for unit tests? I would remove that and create a new store for each test. They are unit test, so you don't want them effecting each other and it is best practice to start each test with a clean store. So I would wrap your configureStore in a createStore function and export that and use it for every test. Your api looks correct and I don't think the issue is in your component, can you share the rest of your store.ts ? I think all the logic for persist should be in there and you can export it from there.

Comment: Also, do you have `import {store} from '../redux/store';` at the top of your jest.setup? that's easy to forget and can give some weird errors.